# How to passing queryset inside static url in django template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

So, I have image in static folder, with the name of image same with username field that I have created. I want to show the photo for every posting based on the post that made by that user. I just thinking to pass the queryset inside static url like this:

```
{% for post in data %}
<img src="{% static 'project/image/{{ post.username }}.jpg' %}" alt="Profile" id="profile_image">
{% endfor %}
```

But my image don't want to show up (error), and the terminal looks like this:

```
[27/Feb/2021 15:43:14] "GET /static/project/image/%7B%7B%20post.username%20%7D%7D.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1758
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the curly brackets, then you need to hard code the whole path of the image.

`static/project/image/{{ post.username }}.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

It uses `{{ post.username }}` as text, and then percentage encodes it. In order to interpret it, just remove the curly brackets and work with the [**`|add:`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#add):

```
{% with post.username|add:".png" as username %}
<img src="{% static 'project/image/'|add:username %}" alt="Profile" id="profile_image">
{% endwith %}
```

For example:

```
>>> Template('{% load static %}{% with post.username|add:".png" as username %}{% static "project/image/"|add:username %}{% endwith %}').render(Context({'post': {'username': 'foo'}}))
'/static/project/image/foo.png'
```

That being said, this is quite complicated. If you work with a [**`FileField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#filefield), then you can convert this to media URLs, and render this with `{{ myobject.myfilefield.url }}`.

Comment: That should end with {% endwith %}, but still it gives error in terminal, [27/Feb/2021 16:15:37] "GET /static/project/image/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1662. It looks like django can't read it

Comment: @IdoYudhatama: I forgot to remove the closing brackets, and locally it works with sample data. Are you sure that you define the temporary variable as `username`, and then use `|add` *without* quotation marks?

Comment: @IdoYudhatama: see edit for a working example.

Comment: Yes, I try again and it still doesn't work. I'm quite sure because I copy for your solution and just replace some value, adjusting with my template